# How to put div in every 5th row laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to put another code of div in every 5th row. Something like:

```
@foreach ($vip_ads as $key=>$ad)
        @if($key%30==0)         {
            <div></div>
        }
        @include('front.ad.ad_template.view')
@endforeach
@foreach ($ads as $key=>$ad)
        @if($key%30==0)         {
            <div></div>
        }
        @include('front.ad.ad_template.view')
@endforeach
```

My laravel version is 4. So I can't use new loop->iteration function. The problem is that it doesn't give a new block to a div. Everything in one line, meanwhile I need to close 5th row (6 columns total 30 elements) and put a new div, after that continue with the given $key value until it gets for example 60. And the next problem is that I could have less than 10 values in $vip_ads, but in total it has to be 30 for both $vip_ads and $ads. Sorry, for my english. Example of this can seen at http://zaza.iknobel.kz/catalog-ad/index/17

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0):

I use only laravel 5.x but your code is not bad, be carefull your key have to be numeric, or add $i=0; before with php and $i++ in the loop

```
@foreach ($vip_ads as $key=>$ad)
    @if($key%5==0)
        <div></div>
    @endif
    @include('front.ad.ad_template.view')
@endforeach
```

or

```
<?php $id=0;?>
@foreach ($vip_ads as $ad)
    <?php $i++;?>
    @if($i%5==0)
        <div></div>
    @endif
    @include('front.ad.ad_template.view')
@endforeach
```

Edit :
Use something like bootstrap with col-md-3 for ad_template (A) and col-md-12 for div (-----) it will look like this :

```
A A A A
-------
A A A A
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I edited my code. The main problem is that I can't separate new div from the front.ad.ad_template.view. Everything goes in one row as one element. And not in every 5th element, but in every 5th row (it means in every 30th element, cause I have 6 columns and 5 rows, total 30)

Comment: if you use bootstrap like grid system, in your ad_template use something like col-md-3 for ad_template, and col-md-12 for the div.

Comment: but how can I count total of two variables, for example I've 8 of $vip_ads and 48 $ads, my $key for $vip_ads starts from 1 to 8, then it counts again for $ads. I would like to continue first $key value for the $ads $key

Comment: If you use the blade loops, you don't even need to declare your own iteration counter you can use [the loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable) more specific the index of the loop variable